# SOLR 'scores' resulting from queries

Tags: lucene, solr4

When using the **Solr web interface** for querying my indexed collection, after I have specified fl=*,scores , for having the scores related to each result of the query, I obtained scores (all equals to 1 or 2) which I cannot understand. I am using SchemaSimilarityFactory.

Why they are integer numbers? What is their meaning ?

Furthermore , when I specify **debugQuery** (checking the box in the interface), the trace of the debugging does not include the tf, idf, or the number of hits in each document. I would like to have  a speaking debugging info with these values. What should I do to solve these problems ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a search with

```
*:*
```

You can not calculate a score if you don't make a specific search because all the docs will have the same score without specyfing a value for a field.

In your debug section, you can see :

```
MatchAllDocsQuery
```

If you want to have a result that can be usefull, you have to do a specific search like for example

```
name:x
```

**Edit:**

To observe tf, idf, ..., you can see source page (Ctrl + U).